# android how an EditText work as AutoComplete

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my `EditText` should work as `AutoComplete`, for that I write in XML file

```
android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
```

but it's not working.

I am working with API v2.2 and my Activity extends `MapActivity`, there I put a simple `EditText` and a button named "Search". so if we type the location name in `EditText` and press search button means it should go to that location in map.
So I want that `EditText` to work as a `AutoComplete`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just use an `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of normal `EditText`.

[hello-autocomplete](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) will be helpful.

EDIT: The above link looks like has expired. The new page is here: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style#AutoComplete

Comment: Sory, I searched from google first i got AutoCompleteTextView also there. but I thought may be there any other to work on this. Thats why i asked.

Comment: @Jyosna - Why would you want another way? Have you tried the `AutoCompleteTextView`? Does it not solve your problem?

Comment: I want like google search engine, like whatever i write there it should autocomplete. For example i did for location , I just entry some city name into an xml file and that AutoCompleteTextView work for only those city name what i mention in String array in string.xml. But I want my AutoCompleteTextview should work as google search box. How can I do that, Do have any idea?

Comment: I do not know how Google generates its auto completes exactly, but I believe it generates them on a statistical basis.
What you could do is save the search queries to an external file every time the user searches something (or you could use some algorithm to generate better suggestions), and load the auto complete strings at runtime from that file. Just Google Android File Handling, I'm sure you'll find lots of tutorials.

Comment: Here's a nice and easy tutorial http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext It also covers autocomplete through a WebService.

Comment: Can I use this for a multiline edittext with suggestions for comma separated tags?

Answer (score 20):

First convert your `EditText->AutoCompleteTextView`

Then link your XML file to the `AutoCompleteTextView` using a `ArrayAdapter`

Assume that the XML `string-array` you created is named as `list_of_countries` then it can be linked to your `AutoCompleteTextView` as follows:

```
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 14):

I use this code:

[image]

1) On AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

2) On xml layout you must use AutoCompleteTextView instead of EditText.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" />
```

3) Use this on Activity file

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> getEmailAddressAdapter(Context context) {
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
    String[] addresses = new String[accounts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { 
        addresses[i] = accounts[i].name;
    }
    return new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, addresses);
}
```

4) On onCreate activity:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
autoCompleteTextView1.setAdapter(getEmailAddressAdapter(this));
```

Comment: This only shows suggestions after the user starts typing. Also i'm not sure if it it safe with regards to the new permissions in android M.

Answer (score 4):

Default `ArrayAdapter` filters only by the first characters. In case you want to see also words which **contain** the searching keyword, you need to use a custom ArrayAdapter and override its `getView` and `getFilter` methods. Take a look at a complete solution I provided in another StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37298258/1808829

Some code fragment:

```
public class AutoSuggestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // handle view here
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
       // implement filtering here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code for change settings of MultiAutoCompleteTextView

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,codeKeyWords);
MultiAutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView1 = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
autoCompleteTextView1.setAdapter(adapter);
autoCompleteTextView1.setThreshold(1);
autoCompleteTextView1.setTokenizer(new this.CommaTokenizer());
```

And below that code for make spliting words by **space char** and **\n** charactes.. (Why we need this code? Because Normal `multiAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());` like that and it make spliting the words by **','** character, But our code help you to make that spliting by these characters ***'  ' and '\n'*** )

```
/**
         * This simple Tokenizer can be used for lists where the items are
         * separated by a comma and one or more spaces.
         */
    public static class CommaTokenizer implements Tokenizer {
        public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;

            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ') {
                i--;
            }
            while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                i++;
            }

            return i;
        }

        public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
            int i = cursor;
            int len = text.length();

            while (i < len) {
                if (text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                    return i;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            return len;
        }

        public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
            int i = text.length();

            while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                i--;
            }

            if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                return text;
            } else {
                if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + "\n");
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                                            Object.class, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return text + " ";
                }
            }
        }
```