# How to auto fill the email edittext with the email id by which the device is registered

Tags: android, email, autocomplete, android-edittext

I want to auto-complete an emailId EditText with the gmail-id registered with the device.
e.g  if my phone is registered with the gmail id **sd@gmail.com** then it should be auto completed as i start typing "s". Any Ideas??? Thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: in your app it has to auto complete your registered email ??

Comment: Just an idea. once you get the id, instead of auto-fill why don't you set it as a hint? U can use setHint()

Comment: yes @shubhayu thats good one. but you cannot select hint. so when you click on hint it disappears. 

So i made an ArrayAdapter out of these results and  took AutoCompleteTextView instead of EditText.
Now works as expected.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39998008/1307387

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go through Android AccountManager class:

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE); 
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
```

and also need to add required permissions to AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

From there you can autofill info.

Comment: @Dallas Substantially editing the content of someone else's answer is not appropriate. You may post your content as a new separate answer. Rolling this answer back, do not repeat it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico you should probably roll back to the version prior to the major edit, then, as that one had spelling/grammar/syntax fixes.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly set this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

The Java code:

```
//declaration

String possibleEmail="";

//onCreate

EditText emailEdt=new EditText(this);

 Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) 
{

  // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat

  // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values.
    possibleEmail = account.name;

}
emailEdt.setText(possibleEmail);
```