# EditText with MultiAutocomplete Dynamic Text Select

Tags: android, autocomplete, multiautocompletetextview

I want to make EditText Card like View that have autocomplete feature , and auto completes are fetched using `retrofit` api , example can be shown below:

[image: Autocomplete edittext]

Can you suggest some easy to use gitHub library to implement this View in android or suggest the possibilities?

Note:

This question is entirely different from `hello autocompletion` because i am asking about custom api's and my view is very much different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android how an EditText work as AutoComplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488727/android-how-an-edittext-work-as-autocomplete)

Comment: You can use [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html). Follow official android document.

Comment: How can i possibly create this much complex view using official documentation , if i know how to do it why would i bother to ask

Answer (score 1):

check out [this one](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) and [this one](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

google has it's own chips but I don't know why they don't publish that for developers.